# How to disable (make inactive/grey out) File button in MS Office document

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I try to disable File button in MS Word.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axWQw.png)
I know that we can disable backstage using customUI.xml:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<backstage>
<button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/>
<button idMso="FileSaveAs" visible="false"/>
<button idMso="FileOpen" visible="false"/>
<button idMso="FileClose" visible="false"/>
<button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
...
</backstage>
</customUI>
```

But i need to fully disable button. User should have no abilities even click it. I must hide backstage from users. I saw similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435554/how-to-disable-file-button-in-ms-word-2013). This has 1 answer which says

> It's not possible to hide this button

Also, Edraw library has such possibility [link](https://www.edrawsoft.com/disable-office-button.php). Someone has any thought?

Comment: The linked question is the same as this. Please try to edit that one as this would be a duplicate...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable File button in MS-Word 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435554/how-to-disable-file-button-in-ms-word-2013)

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the File tab requires you to hide the default ribbon:

```
<CustomUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/CustomUI"> <ribbon startFromScratch="true"/></CustomUI>
```

Then replace it with a new ribbon that you design from scratch.

Comment: It doesn't work. It removes all Ribbon tabs, but File tab still exists.